# Segmentation fault in fgets

Tags: c

After debugging my code I get the following error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0xb7d79a67 in fgets () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Can anybody explain to me what this means? It's a project built using CMake and OpenGL.

Comment: It means that `fgets` accessed memory it wasn't supposed to.  But that is because you will have used it incorrectly...

Comment: It was confirmed open the file or not?

Comment: One common reason is that you've forgotten to check that fopen actually managed to open the file you then read from. But use a debugger to find the exact location in your code, and inspect the variables.

Comment: Try checking return value of fopen. What if it's NULL? Because it is likely that your "file name" has trailing \n.

Comment: @AnishRam in one way he doesn't seem lazy... he didn't post his code and asked us to debug... he was just asking what the specific error means? googling his specific error only returns 3 results and all about this question in stackoverflow only which means actaul results are zero. he not only want's to know what is `SEGSEGV` but also interpretation of that error sentence.... It's a specific programming question for sure... that's why this question is not closed yet... I think... ) No offense intended by the way ::)

Comment: @pinkpanther, Not at all. In fact the very first result (at least for me) is the [Wikipedia article on a Segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). I highly doubt any answer here can outdo that. Now once he/she has read aforementioned article, the next step would be to [google "debug segmentation fault"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=debug+segmentation+fault&oq=debug+segmentation+fault&aqs=chrome.0.0j60j0l3j62.2702j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The first link there points to a [gdb tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html) (contd.)

Comment: @pinkpanther, Once through the gdb tutorial, he/she should check the [`fgets` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) for usage specifics. If he/she still does not know what is wrong, THEN post here with all the results of the effort. Then everyone, especially me, will be extremely happy to help because we know the OP has put in effort. Also, no offence taken :)

Comment: @AnishRam you might have searched it using `SEGSEGV` only... but search using `SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7d79a67 in fgets () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`... he might need interpretation...like what is `fgets () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` mean.... in that case `SIGSEGV` is might not be sufficient....

Answer (score 1):

When a program tries to access memory it has no privileges, the `Linux Kernel` interrupts the program by sending a signal called `SEGSEGV`. In your `fgets`, may be you are exceeding the memory you have allocated for your pointer by inputting too much text. Signals is one way the `Linux Kernel` communicates with the programs (processes in correct sense). It's kind of exception.

Since, you are dealing with files. It's worth checking if your file actually exists. May be you don't have privileges to read the file and hence getting the error.

`/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` is a shared library on your `Linux` system in which `fgets` function resides and `0xb7d79a67` is (I guess) main memory address your program doesn't have privileges may be goes beyond the file length.

The `segmentation-fault(SEGSEGV)` can occur when you access protected memory areas, or the memory areas which are used by other programs and hence your program doesn't have any right to access.

Read these articles for better grasp:
      [Segmentation fault why?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/segmentation-fault-on-linux-unix.html), [Debugging segmentation faults](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html)

Comment: In my case, I believe I am getting a segfault because I am trying to run a protected binary in gdb on a capture-the-flag server. I thought I could just set the program counter or $rip to the target function, but perhaps running the program in gdb prevents it from being able to access files my user can't read.

This is the first answer in many threads that actually provided some context. 7 years late but thank you for the help!